# Read Kernel Memory from user mode WITHOUT driver

Tags: c, windows, kernel, driver

I'm writing an program which enumerates hooks created by `SetWindowsHookEx()` Here is the process:

1. Use `GetProcAddress()` to obtain `gSharedInfo` exported in `User32.dll`(works, verified)
2. Read User-Mode memory at `gSharedInfo + 8`, the result should be a pointer of first handle entry. (works, verified)
3. Read User-Mode memory at `[gSharedInfo] + 8`, the result should be `count`of handles to enumerate. (works, verified)
4. Read data from address obtained in step 2, repeat `count` times
5. Check if `HANDLEENTRY.bType` is 5(which means it's a HHOOK). If so, print informations.

The problem is, although step 1-3 only mess around with user mode memory, step 4 requires the program to read kernel memory. After some research I found that `ZwSystemDebugControl` can be used to access Kernel Memory from user mode. So I wrote the following function:

```
BOOL GetKernelMemory(PVOID pKernelAddr, PBYTE pBuffer, ULONG uLength)
{
    MEMORY_CHUNKS mc;
    ULONG uReaded = 0;
    mc.Address = (UINT)pKernelAddr;  //Kernel Memory Address - input
    mc.pData = (UINT)pBuffer;//User Mode Memory Address  - output
    mc.Length = (UINT)uLength;       //length  
    ULONG st = -1;
    ZWSYSTEMDEBUGCONTROL ZwSystemDebugControl = (ZWSYSTEMDEBUGCONTROL)GetProcAddress(
    GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), "NtSystemDebugControl");
    st = ZwSystemDebugControl(SysDbgCopyMemoryChunks_0, &mc, sizeof(MEMORY_CHUNKS), 0, 0, &uReaded);
    return st == 0;
}
```

But the function above didn't work. `uReaded` is always 0 and `st` is always 0xC0000002. How do I resolve this error?

my full program:
http://pastebin.com/xzYfGdC5

Comment: Does your program have the SeDebugPrivilege privilege?  Reading kernel memory is something an antivirus program would want to prevent. Are you sure that is not a problem?

Comment: Yes I did have DEBUG privilege. I tried shutdown Antivirus but didn't help. @user34660

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSFT did not implement `NtSystemDebugControl` syscall after windows XP.

Comment: On Vista and newer, the \Device\PhysicalMemory section cannot be opened from user mode. I think there are no ways of reading physical/kernel memory from application left.

Answer (score 1):

The [Meltdown](https://meltdownattack.com/) vulnerability makes it possible to read Kernel memory from User Mode on most Intel CPUs with a speed of approximately 500kB/s.  This works on most unpatched OS'es.